# LINQ project() to automap from data entity to business entity within LINQ IQueryable?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, automapper, iqueryable

I'm not sure this is possible.

Some requirements

- Our queries are IQueryable all the way through.
- All parameters passed via OData
- Entities and Business Entities are separate Our queries should only
- return Business Entities, not Data Entities

here's what we're trying to do

```
var query = from mpg in this.markingPeriodGroupRepository.GetAll()
            join mp in this.markingPeriodRepository.GetAll().Include(x => x.SchoolMarkingPeriods) 
                on mpg.MarkingPeriodGroupID equals mp.MarkingPeriodGroupID
            select new MarkingPeriodTerm
            {
                MarkingPeriodGroupID = mpg.MarkingPeriodGroupID,
                MarkingPeriodGroupName = mpg.MarkingPeriodGroupName,
                SchoolMarkingPeriods = mp.SchoolMarkingPeriods.AsQueryable()
                    .Project().To<SchoolMarkingPeriod>(null).ToList()
            };
```

At run time, we get this error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[NHA.App.Core.v2.Business.Models.SchoolMarkingPeriod] To[SchoolMarkingPeriod](System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[System.String,System.Object])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Is it possible to automap this property within this IQueryable?

Comment: The question is not very clear. What is OData and Data? Can you also provide the code of the entities? Specially, what is the definition of mp.SchoolMarkingPeriods?

Comment: I'm trying to find a way to structure my question in a clearer way.  Hmm...basically, I don't want to .Project() in AutoMapper to try to convert that to SQL, rather a deferred execution of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: your best bet is building the selector Expression yourself. Technically it is a `NewExpression` with member init and I doubt that `To` method cannot be converted to a translatable Expression ***anyway***, meaning you still have to use another `NewExpression` to project for a `SchoolMarkingPeriod` yourself (to init the member `SchoolMarkingPeriods`. It's quite complicated but it is the only approach to satisfy your requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your query, select an anonymous type and don't execute the Project method yet.

```
var query = from mpg in this.markingPeriodGroupRepository.GetAll()
            join mp in this.markingPeriodRepository.GetAll().Include(x => x.SchoolMarkingPeriods)
                on mpg.MarkingPeriodGroupID equals mp.MarkingPeriodGroupID
            select new //Here we are selecting an anonymous type
            {
                MarkingPeriodGroupID = mpg.MarkingPeriodGroupID,
                MarkingPeriodGroupName = mpg.MarkingPeriodGroupName,
                SchoolMarkingPeriods = mp.SchoolMarkingPeriods   
            };
```

Then, after executing the query, we can use the Project method.

```
var result = query
    .ToList() //This will actually execute the query.
    .Select(x => new MarkingPeriodTerm()
    {
        MarkingPeriodGroupID = x.MarkingPeriodGroupID,
        MarkingPeriodGroupName = x.MarkingPeriodGroupName,
        SchoolMarkingPeriods = x.SchoolMarkingPeriods.Project().To<SchoolMarkingPeriod>(null).ToList() //Here we are executing the Project method on in-memory data
    });
```

Comment: Hmm..yeah, i played with that, but then of course my IQueryable is broken.

Comment: How is it broken? Can you explain?

Comment: Once I execute the .ToList on the primary query, Its no longer an IQueryable (.ToList() //This will actually execute the query.).    This would execute my query but without my OData parameters that get passed in.

Comment: let me try this though.

Comment: Ok. I cannot see the OData parameters in your question.

Comment: yes, sorry i didn't mention what the actual OData parameters were since I wanted to preserve IQueryable throughout and keep the deferred execution.

Comment: Please update your question to include information about these OData parameters.